Excel - Create 'Next' after spill range
I may be reaching the extent of excel's capabilities without getting into VBA (out of my depth).
I need the "Product Collumn" (Collumn B) to automatically populate (Spill) the subsequent value from Req Products (H3#). The tricky part is I need this to happen once the spill table from Collumn C (for each product) has finished populating the rows it needs.
So instead of each 'Product' having a set size of 7-rows, these will neatly fit together.
For reference H3# is also a spill range that references a table I will likely add data too. Thus, I need this to grow dynamically. I do not care if the cells in Collumn B are merged or repeated for each row, relavent to the size of spill in Collumn C.
Sample Spreadsheet Image
